# C: Simple pointer question

Tags: c, pointers

I want to program an access function that returns username and password. Here's what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *
getMySQLUsername()
{
    return "myUsername";
}

char *
getMySQLPassword()
{
    return "myPassword";
}

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", getMySQLPassword());
}
```

It seems to work, but is this code correct?

Comment: May fix it by :
/////////////////////////
const static char* result = "myUserName";

return result;
//////////////////////

Comment: @Henry: That would add an extra mutable (non-constant) variable to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should return `const char *` because you cannot change a literal string.  You're also not returning anything from `main`, which is only valid in C as of C99 and in C++.

Comment: for this kind of usage you'll probably want `const char* const`

Comment: What is the benefit to having the extra `const`, yi_H?

Comment: @yi_H: There is no need to declare a return value `const` because it is not an lvalue.  So `const char *` is fine.

Comment: @Sydius- `const char* const` says two things: the pointer is constant (that's the second one), and the data that it points to is also constant (that's the first `const`).  As Dietrich Epp explained, the return value from a function is always constant, so only the first `const` is needed.

Comment: ahh.. right. that const modifier only makes sense for the clients of the function who store its returned value. thx!

Comment: @bta, I don't think it's always constant; I think it's just always an rvalue (the difference being subtle and on my mind having been playing with C++0x and rvalue references).  I couldn't imagine a reason to make it const.